# how to export a chart with achartengine?

Tags: android, charts, export, achartengine

I have a chart, I export to jpg or png and save it in the SD, the truth is that I find as I watched it official but also the documentation I could not find what you want to do

Comment: Solution for the same problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22135536/android-achartengine-trying-to-export-graph-as-image-throws-exception

Answer (score 0):

You can export the layout where the graph is drawn. Layouts are really easy converted into images!