# android achartengine : trying to export graph as image throws exception

Tags: android, achartengine

in an android app, am attempting to export the graph (which I drew using achartengine) as Bitmap object via this code

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(Context context, View view) {

    Bitmap bitmap;

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPurgeable = true;
    options.inInputShareable = true;

    Bitmap dummy = null;
    try {
        dummy = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getAssets().open("icon_add.png"), new Rect(-1,-1,-1,-1), options);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getLayoutParams().width,
        view.getLayoutParams().height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.layout(0, 0, view.getLayoutParams().width, view.getLayoutParams().height);
    view.draw(c);
    c = null;

    return bitmap;
}
```

and am calling this method as:

```
loadBitmapFromView(getApplicationContext(), this.graphView);
```

where graphView is the object of type GraphicalView

But this is throwing the exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
```

at this line

```
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getLayoutParams().width,
        view.getLayoutParams().height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
```

can someone please help?

Comment: If you use the debugger or `Log.d()` to display the values of `view.getLayoutParams().width` and `view.getLayoutParams().height`, what does that show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLayoutParams() that method returns the

> ... layout parameters. These supply parameters to the parent of this view
>   specifying how it should be arranged.

i.e. these are inputs to the layout computation:

> LayoutParams ... describes how big the view wants to be for both width and height. For each
>   dimension, it can specify one of an exact number, MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT

You need the actual View size, that is, the result of the layout computation.

If this View is already laid out on screen, then `view.getWidth()` and `view.getHeight()` should return its actual size. In that case, calling `view.layout(...)` may put the displayed View in a weird state that you should restore, and again you want to pass actual size info, not layout params.

If this View is not on screen, then `view.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)` is supposed to be called before `view.layout(...)`. Do read the [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) docs.