# achartengine android : issue when exporting graph that is longer than device width

Tags: android, achartengine

In an Android App, am drawing a line chart with AChartEngine. The chart exceeds the device width, meaning you need to pan to see the entire graph. That is, it doesn't fit in one screen. Am trying to extract this graph as an image, with this code:

```
     bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(deviceWidth * 2,
        deviceHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);  
     Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth() * 2, view.getMeasuredHeight() + 15);
    view.draw(c);   // view is the GraphicalView where the graph is drawn
```

It works fine when the graph fits into one screen (i.e. the device width). However, when the graph is longer than the screen's width, it only exports what is seen on the screen. However, am able to see the annotations (i.e. text) of all the plots. But the image has only the lines that are within the screen width. How come annotations get drawn, but not the line plottings?
Can someone please help?

Comment: I'm passing through the same issue. Have you found a solution?

Comment: This is for performance reasons, data that is not on the screen is not displayed. In order to skip this, you will have to extend AChartEngine in order to support this feature.

Comment: @lucasdc  Have you found a solution?

Comment: [Solution for the same problem is here-][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22135536/android-achartengine-trying-to-export-graph-as-image-throws-exception